# js Подстановка переменной в строку

Tags: javascript

Случайно наткнулся на конструкцию для вставки переменных в строку:

```
var name = "World";
console.log(`Hello ${name}!`); // выведет "Hello World!"
```

Что за фича и как давно существует? Всегда пользовался конкатенацией или replace/replaceObject если была необходимость...

```
console.log('Hello ' + name + '!');
console.log('Hello {name}!'.replace('{name}', name));
console.log('Hello {name}!'.replaceObject({'name': name});
```

Comment: шаблонные [строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

Comment: @Jean-Claude Спасибо! Новый js не перестает радовать

Answer (score 23):

Шаблонные строки (шаблоны) является строковыми литералами, допускающими использование выражений. Вы можете использовать многострочные литералы и возможности интерполяции.

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;
console.log(`Fifteen is ${a + b} and not ${2 * a + b}.`);
// "Fifteen is 15 and not 20."
```

[Документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings).