# Как в JS вставить адрес картинки из массива arr в div.style.backgroundImage = "url('arr[i]')"

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь изменить картинку в div через div.style.backgroundImage. Адрес картинки беру из массива:

```
let backgroundColors = ['slider/redCat.jpg', 'slider/fright.jpg', 'slider/officer.jpg'];
```

Если прописать вручную, то всё получается:

```
slider1.style.backgroundImage = "url('slider/fright.jpg')";
```

Если адрес брать из массива, то не находит пути. Похоже из-за кавычек '':

```
slider1.style.backgroundImage = "url(backgroundColors[1])";
```

Пробовал по-разному, например:

```
slider1.style.backgroundImage = `"url('${backgroundColors[1]}')"`;
```

Comment: строку и переменную обычно склеивают конкатекацией с помощью плюса `"url(" + backgroundColors[1] + ")"` либо так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/500234/js-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83/500235#500235

Comment: из последнего примера двойные кавычки уберите, и должно все работать. но пути лучше указывайте от корня `/`

Comment: одинарные, впрочем, тоже не нужны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так:

```
slider1.style.backgroundImage = `url('${backgroundColors[1]}')`;
```

Либо:

```
slider1.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + backgroundColors[1] + '")';
```

Comment: Помог и первый и второй вариант. Премного благодарен